# Переделать график из Highcharts

Tags: javascript, mysql, график, highcharts

Всем добрый день!

Нужно сделать график.
Очень понравился такой https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-ajax
Но вот беда. Надо, чтобы данные брались из MySQL, а не из файла CSV.
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: json ему более чем подходит

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо чуток конфиги поменять: добавить массив данных `data` к `series` и удалить `data: { csv: csv },` из основного.

```
series: [{
    name: 'All visits',
    lineWidth: 4,
    marker: {
        radius: 4
    },
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'New visitors',
    data: [43934, 52503, 54177, 69258, 97121, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1mnxfwd/

Comment: А вот я получаю с помощью php-файла данные из БД наподобие JSON. Как мне их в data прикрутить?

Comment: json_encode($data)

Comment: Это я понял, я запустил php-файл отдельно, получил массив. А как прикрутить результаты к двум data?

Comment: у вас есть график линии 1, собираете массив точек, преобразуете через json_encode и вставляете его в первый data. Также со вторым.

Comment: В JS есть какая-либо функция, которая в качестве аргумента берёт файл php, а в результате выводит массив данных?

Comment: @МихаилДремург лекции по базовым вещам php/js давать в комментариях не буду :)